# querySelectorAll and innerHTML logic

Tags: javascript

I can't build logic of JavaScript in this case. Why "Dollar" don't changes to "Dolor", and "dollar" to "dolor"? But at the same time background styling matches. What's wrong with my logic? Thank you.

```js
var dollarEls = document.querySelectorAll("li .dollar");
        for (var i = 0; i < dollarEls.length; i++) {
                if(dollarEls[i] == "Dollar") {
                  dollarEls[i].innerHTML = "Dolor";
                }else if (dollarEls[i] == "dollar") {
                  dollarEls[i].innerHTML = "dolor";
                }else {
                  dollarEls[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
                }
        }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum <span class="dollar">Dollar</span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mi tortor, convallis vitae rhoncus suscipit, finibus a dui. Quisque congue vulputate dolor vel facilisis. Nunc non ipsum porta, efficitur odio euismod, facilisis erat.</li>

    <li>Nam <span class="dollar">Dollar</span> ante, faucibus nec enim consequat, auctor faucibus nulla. Etiam bibendum commodo elit at euismod. Nullam elementum varius ligula sit amet accumsan. Nunc arcu nunc, mattis quis mollis eget, ultricies a nisi. Aliquam maximus luctus magna, vitae feugiat <span class="dollar">dollar</span> tempus non. Nulla dui ante, tempus at justo ut, ultricies cursus mauris.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Apart from the obvious error, don't use `innerHTML`, but `textContent`.

Comment: I'm confused. You obviously know that you can use `innerHTML` to set the element's value; why wouldn't you also use that to consult/examine/retrieve the element's value? Anyway, why exactly are you needing to do this?

Comment: If to be honest, I was trying to understand how to solve additional task from Khan Academy "Query modernizer". As I see, I don't understand clearly DOM innerHTML property. Thanks for attention and advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saying

```
if(dollarEls[i] == "Dollar")
```

say

```
if(dollarsEls[i].innerHTML == "Dollar");
```

Replace both such occurences

```js
var dollarEls = document.querySelectorAll("li .dollar");
    for (var i = 0; i < dollarEls.length; i++) {
        if (dollarEls[i].innerHTML == "Dollar") {
            dollarEls[i].innerHTML = "Dolor";
        } else if (dollarEls[i].innerHTML == "dollar") {
            dollarEls[i].innerHTML = "dolor";
        } else {
            dollarEls[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum <span class="dollar">Dollar</span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mi tortor, convallis vitae rhoncus suscipit, finibus a dui. Quisque congue vulputate dolor vel facilisis. Nunc non ipsum porta, efficitur odio euismod, facilisis erat.</li>

    <li>Nam <span class="dollar">Dollar</span> ante, faucibus nec enim consequat, auctor faucibus nulla. Etiam bibendum commodo elit at euismod. Nullam elementum varius ligula sit amet accumsan. Nunc arcu nunc, mattis quis mollis eget, ultricies a nisi. Aliquam maximus luctus magna, vitae feugiat <span class="dollar">dollar</span> tempus non. Nulla dui ante, tempus at justo ut, ultricies cursus mauris.</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're testing if the string representation of the HTML Element Object is equal to the string or not, instead of reading its text content (with `innerHTML`).